# How can Automator or Applescript rotate 500,000 images in folders and subfolders?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, automator, image-editing

I have very specific question.

I've got 500,000 images that sit in 98 subfolders. Some of the subfolders contain 25,000 images.

Is there any script/automator workflow that I can use?

I was trying to create a workflow:

1. Ask for Finder Items
2. Get Folder Contents (tick repeat for each subfolder found)
3. Rotate images

It works OK, but only for these folders where there is less than 4,096 files:
I normally receive following error message:

```
Rotate images failed - 1 error too many arguments (12019) -- limit is 4096
```

Is there any way to increase this limit or create completely different apple script?
I really hope that someone will help me with this one.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not bound to use Automator or AppleScript, simply use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) through the shell. You can install ImageMagick through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [Homebrew](https://mxcl.dev/homebrew/), or the [official distribution](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx).

To do this, we'll call `find`. If you want to see the names of the images first, before *actually* converting them, insert an `echo` between `-execdir` and `convert`.

Here's the command:

```
find /some/path/ -type f -iname "*.jpg" -execdir convert {} -rotate 90 rot_{} \;
```

This will recursively …

- search `/some/path`
- for files
- with the name `*.jpg`
- call [`convert`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) from ImageMagick, with the working path set to the image's one ([`execdir`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files))
- rotate them `90` degrees
- save them under `rot_` + the original filename

Since `find` will call `convert` for each image separately, it doesn't matter how many files there actually are.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sips...

Assuming every file in the folders is an image file:

```
set mainFolder to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "My Folder"
do shell script "find " & quoted form of mainFolder & " \\! -name \".*\" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sips -r 90"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jpegtran to rotate images losslessly. It can be installed with `brew install libjpeg`.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for f in $(find ~/Folder -iname '*.jpg'); do
    /usr/local/bin/jpegtran -rotate 90 "$f" > "$f.temp"
    [[ $? == 0 ]] && mv "$f.temp" "$f" || echo "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). You tell Hazel which folders (and subfolders) to check, set up the criteria for files to be acted upon, and the actions to take (including scripts, shell scripts and workflows) and Hazel does the rest.